# Does train 006K Ukrania from Kyiv to Moscow have a dining car?

Tags: trains, food-and-drink, russia, ukraine

I'm booked this evening on the train mentioned in the title. We were wondering whether there would be food or drinks available - I gather there would usually be tea from the attendant, but besides that, will there be any place to sit and eat or drink, and mingle with the other passengers (albeit through a language barrier!)?

Comment: The language barrier between Ukrainian and Russian is not huge, in particular since many/most Ukrainians understand Russian.

Comment: I don't speak either! :) (well, I can say basic things like Privet, Spasibo, Da Svidanye, and Eto ne moi narkotiki, but not much else)

Comment: If you want to mingle with other passengers, get yourself a place in the плацкартный вагон (couchette car, or a "3-cl. open sleeping car" by the RZD designation). With any bit of luck you'll find some people in your car willing to chat. That said, you'll have no privacy and will most likely be assaulted by offensive smells of boiled chicken, sweat and cheap tobacco throughout your whole journey, however, that will be as authentic an experience as you could ever get.

Comment: @undercat I would not translate *плацкартный* with *couchette*.  In western Europe, couchettes traditionally are lockable compartments with 4-6 (mixed gender or single gender) bunks.  Western Europe AFAIK doesn't have anything comparable with плацкартный, although in Canada VIA Rail have sections (which they market at berths) that are somewhat comparable in layout, although not in culture.

Comment: [This article (in Russian)](https://biz.censor.net.ua/news/3080794/v_ukrzaliznytse_ne_vidyat_smysla_v_soderjanii_vagonovrestoranov) explains that Ukrainian Railway is reluctant to keep these cars and they only have then on three routes. Three other routes have "dining half-cars". Trains on the route you are interested in are not mentioned to have either of the two.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After having travelled on this train, I can confirm that there is no restaurant car or bar. You can of course still buy tea from the attendant!